# how to update values in database where date = systemdate

Tags: c#, sql, database, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I have created a database application in C#. The program send automatically system date when it open. I have given this code to loading.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO summery_data
                         (date, total_h, work_h, delay_h, tfif, tth, th)
VALUES        (GetDate(),'','','','','','')", con);
```

so now I want to Update other values of the the table according to the date in database.

ex:-

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE       summery_data
SET                tth ='" + test + " ' WHERE       date = '?????????????')", con);
```

the date should be Today system date;
Please help me to do that...!

Comment: You should have a tag related to sql.

Comment: Use `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now` , and use `dt.Day` , `dt.Month` , `dt.Year`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date column is a data type date and not datetime, you could strip off the time stamp from GetDate() to get an accurate match..

Update summary_data
Set tth = 'blah'
Where date = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

If the data type is a datetime then you can strip off the time stamp for both date and getdate() to get an accurate match..

Update summary_data
Set tth = 'blah'
Where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date), 0) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)